# How do I find a matrix $S$ such that $S^\top A \, S$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $0,-1,1$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&2\\2&1&-2\\2&-2&1\end{pmatrix}$$ whose eigenvalues are $3,-3,-3$, how can I find a such a regular matrix $S$?

Comment: We can actually post the matrix and other mathematical expressions using [MathJax and $\LaTeX$](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Find the eigenvectors. Why are the eigenvalues a problem? Note that $S$ is symmetric.

Comment: You could start by getting the correct multiplicities.

Comment: The eigenvectores are (1,1,0) (1,0,1) for eigenvalue 3 and (-1,1,1) for eigenvalue -3

Comment: But then S^t A S is not diagonal

Comment: That is because your first two eigenvectors are not orthogonal.